# Jar file run on a server background with close putty session

Tags: jar, server, putty

I have tried the run spring boot jar file using putty. but the problem is after closed the putty session service was stopped.

Comment: If you want to launch it from terminal, you can use `screen` or `tmux`.
But a better way is to run it as a service, please check official docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. And if you put your question title to google, you will find a zillions of same questions on [sf], [su] and https://unix.stackexchange.com/ (where would your question belong, were it not a duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

then i tried up the jar file with following command. its working fine .

**nohup java -jar /web/server.jar **

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using nohup as it will just disassociate your terminal and the process. Instead, use the following command to run your process as a service.

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/your-spring-boot-app.jar /etc/init.d/your-spring-boot-app
```

This command creates a symbolic link to your JAR file. Which then, you can run as a service using the command `sudo service your-spring-boot-app start`. This will write console log to `/var/log/your-spring-boot-app.log`

Moreover, you can configure spring-boot/`application.properties` to write console logs at your specified location using `logging.path=path-to-your-log-directory`or `logging.file=path-to-your-log-file.txt`. Also, it may be worth noting that `logging.file` takes priority over `logging.path`